# Calculating Angular Acceleration using Torque and Rotational Inertia

Tags: homework-and-exercises, torque

I don't understand why my approach to this problem is wrong.

> Two masses, one with mass $m$, and the other with mass $2m$, are attached
> to a light rigid rod as shown below. When the system is released from
> rest, the rod begins to rotate with an angular acceleration of $-g/(9L)$.

However, I got $g/(7L)$.
[image]

My method is using torque, but not inertia and angular acceleration.
$$F = ma = m \alpha r \tau = mar = m \alpha r \cdot r$$
$$2mgL - 4mgL = 2m \alpha L^2 - 16m \alpha L^2 \alpha = g/(7L)$$

I do not understand why my approach is wrong.

Comment: And why not use $\tau = I\alpha$?

Comment: That is the original solution, but I tried solving it in a different way and I don't get why it gives another answer.

Comment: Your equations are very unclear. Please check my edit and make further adjustments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using Newton's equations per se, you are basically using the Newton's equations for rotation when multiplying by the position.

Your error comes when you wrote $2-16$, when it's actually $2 + 16$. The minus sign that you written comes from the $-4L$, but it's squared, so it goes away.

It's the same approach than using $\tau = I \alpha$.